# HTTP get request only returning results where database values id are continuous (1, 2, 3) in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, httprequest, angular-httpclient, behaviorsubject

I have a table in my database where the ids of the values are not continuous, for example:

1. id: 1, name: john, lastname: doe
2. id: 5, name: tom, lastname: tom

so I want with a get request to get all the values in the table and display them.

All the requests with continuous ids works just fine. I'm using Angular 6 so I now that I don't need to convert my response to a json and then read it. I also checked my request with postman and it return all the values. Here is a part of the response :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Visionwai 2",
        "createdDate": "2019-02-04T12:06:54.1667898",
        "description": "Visionwai à Etincelle",
        "nbrOfEmployees": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Visionwai",
        "createdDate": "2019-02-06T12:23:59.0105529",
        "description": "",
        "nbrOfEmployees": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "t",
        "createdDate": "2019-02-07T11:11:11.123",
        "description": null,
        "nbrOfEmployees": 0
    }
]
```

I have my requestService.ts which simply returns the request, here is the problematic request

```
getClients() {
    var self = this
    return self.http.get(this.connectionString+'clients', 
    self.authorizationToken)
}
```

I have a dataService.ts that will be called in most of my component and allows me to store the requests result so that I don't call a requests every time if the data has already been loaded once.

```
clients = new BehaviorSubject([]);

storeClientsList(load = false){
    if(this.clients.value.length == 0 || load){
        this.requests.getClients()
        .subscribe((clients:any[])  =>{
            console.log(clients)
            this.clients.next(clients)
            console.log('Request executed')
        })
     }
     else{
         this.clients.next(this.clients.value)
     }
     console.log(this.clients)
}
```

Here is the result of the console.log(clients) (same result for console.log(this.clients) it just return the behaviorSubject with this value in it).

```
0:
    createdDate: "2019-02-04T12:06:54.1667898"
    description: "Visionwai à Etincelle"
    id: 1
    name: "Visionwai 2"
    nbrOfEmployees: 5
```

And then in my component, I do operations like this (here filling a mat-select)

```
this.dataService.storeClientsList()

this.dataService.clients
.subscribe(clients => {
    clients.map(client => {
        let data = {value: client.name, viewValue: client.name};
        this.companyList.push(data)
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Can you try GET request using postman? Is it working? If yes can you provide the response?

Comment: I just edited my question  ^^'. The request is working with postman

Comment: console.log(clients)
Does this logs anything in console?

Comment: It returns only the first value, I'm adding it to the question.